# C# project won't compile anymore due to missing reference to Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.4.0.Utilities

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-office, visual-studio-2019

It used to compile just fine but as of today it won't anymore - I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I tried installing the Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime 2010 and closing/reopening the project but that didn't help...

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the `.vs`, the `bin` and the `obj` folders of your project. Open your project again and rebuilt it. This steps will most likely resolve your problem.

Comment: I deleted the `.vs` folder for my solution and the `bin` and `obj` folders for this particular project, but I still get errors and the reference is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Office development workload from the Visual Studio installer and that resolved the reference for me. No idea how it was working before...